# Is it necessary to cast individual indices of a pointer after you cast the whole pointer in c? Why?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

In the code below the address of ip is casted to uint8_t *.
But below again each index of the casted pointer is casted to uint8_t.
Why the programmer has done this? Does it make a difference if we remove all those casts that come after the initial cast? This code converts an IPv4 IP Address to an IP Number.  Thank you

```
uint32_t Dot2LongIP(char* ipstring)
{
    uint32_t ip = inet_addr(ipstring);
    uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *) &ip;
    uint32_t a = 0;

    if (ipstring != NULL) {
        a =  (uint8_t)(ptr[3]);
        a += (uint8_t)(ptr[2]) * 256;
        a += (uint8_t)(ptr[1]) * 256 * 256;
        a += (uint8_t)(ptr[0]) * 256 * 256 * 256;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `ptr[i]` for any valid index `i` already have the type `uint8_t`. There's no need for the individual element cast.

Comment: If this is C++ then there shouldn't be any c-style cast in this code. Please do not confuse C and C++, they are 2 different languages. Only tag both the the question is about interoperation of the two

Comment: What does the shown code accomplish by 1) Converting an IP address to an uint32_t, 2) Picking apart the `uint32_t` address into four `uint8_t` values, and 3) using them to create the same `uint32_t` value that it started out with, in step 1? What is that supposed to accomplish? And does your `inet_addr` really accept a NULL pointer as a valid input parameter?

Comment: By the way, note that `inet_addr` is deprecated in favor of `inet_pton`.

Comment: Use bit shifts instead of multiplication. There's countless examples on SO of how to do that properly.

Comment: The author probably should have checked the return value of `inet_addr` for errors, and replaced all that mucking around with `uint8_t` arrays with a call to `ntohl()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-inet_addr?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WINSOCK2%252Finet_addr);k(inet_addr);k(DevLang-C%252B%252B);k(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue#internet-addresses) it says that the most significant byte of the IP goes to the least significant memory location and vice versa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the programmer has done this?

Ignorance, fear, or other incompetence.

The type of `ptr` is `uint8_t *`, so the type of `ptr[i]` is `uint8_t`. Converting a `uint8_t` to a `uint8_t` has no effect. Also, putting it in parentheses has no effect.

> Does it make a difference if we remove all those casts that come after the initial cast?

Yes, it makes the code smaller and clearer. It has no effect on the program semantics.

> This code converts an IPv4 IP Address to an IP Number.

No, it does not, not correctly; the code is broken.

When the `uint8_t` value is used in multiplication with 256, the usual arithmetic conversions are applied. These promote the `uint8_t` to `int`, and then the result of the `*` operator is an `int`. For `ptr[0]`, as two more multiplications by 256 are performed, the result remains an `int`. Unfortunately, if the high bit (bit 7) of `ptr[0]` is set, these multiplications overflow a 32-bit `int`. Then the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard.

To avoid this, the value should have been cast to `uint32_t`. (This speaks only to getting the arithmetic correct; I make no assertion about the usefulness of taking apart an `in_addr_t` returned by `inet_addr` and reassembling it in this way.)

Comment: I'm *guessing* the original programmer was aware that the code was broken, and that he or she thought that the cast would be enough to fix it (converting the promoted `int` value back to `uint8_t`).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that is Arduino code :)

```
uint32_t Dot2LongIP(char* ipstring)
{
    uint32_t ip = inet_addr(ipstring);
    
    return return nothl(ip);
}
```

or if you do not want to use `htonl`

```
uint32_t Dot2LongIP(char* ipstring)
{
    uint32_t ip = inet_addr(ipstring);
    
    ip = ((ip & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((ip & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) | 
         ((ip & 0x0000ff00) << 8)  | ((ip & 0x000000ff) << 24);

    return ip;
}
```

Comment: `htonl()` likely breaks things on little-endian machines:  [All Internet addresses shall be returned in network order (bytes ordered from left to right).](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_addr.html)

Comment: @AndrewHenle yep - forgot that .._addr function returns it in the network format.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing any index of `ptr` (i.e., `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, etc) will have the type `uint8_t`. The casting performed on them is redundant.